# Highstock Angular value in legend

Tags: highcharts, legend

I'm looking for alternatives for the plug-in values for the legend.
The plug-in uses jQuery and I'm running an Angular 5 application.
Has someone created a solution for that before?

```
labelFormat: '<span style="color:{color}">{name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f} USD</b> ({point.change:.2f}%)<br/>'
```

Here is a [sample of Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DVvdZ/) using jQuery to access the chart container and display the series value on legend.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of jquery you can replace `jquery .bind` method with js `addEventListener` on chart.container. Next, follow [highcharts-angular documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper) and create your own wrapper for this plugin. Check demo posted below.

Value-in-legend.js plugin:

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    factory(Highcharts);
  }
})(function(Highcharts) {
  Highcharts.Series.prototype.point = {}; // The active point
  Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function(chart) {
    chart.container.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
      var legendOptions = chart.legend.options,
        hoverPoints = chart.hoverPoints;

      // Return when legend is disabled (#4)
      if (legendOptions.enabled === false) {
        return;
      }

      if (!hoverPoints && chart.hoverPoint) {
        hoverPoints = [chart.hoverPoint];
      }
      if (hoverPoints) {
        Highcharts.each(hoverPoints, function(point) {
          point.series.point = point;
        });
        Highcharts.each(chart.legend.allItems, function(item) {
          item.legendItem.attr({
            text: legendOptions.labelFormat
              ? Highcharts.format(legendOptions.labelFormat, item)
              : legendOptions.labelFormatter.call(item)
          });
        });
        chart.legend.render();
      }
    });
  });
  // Hide the tooltip but allow the crosshair
  Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.defaultFormatter = function() {
    return false;
  };
});
```

Next, initialize it in your component:

```
require("./path-to-your-file/value-in-legend")(Highcharts);
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j2j7wxwv7y